# jQuery UI Sortable with .parent() Sortable Items Criteria

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, parent-child, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using jQuery UI sortable on a series of divs, and I'd like to make the .button class divs sortable if they contain a div with the active class (ie third button below wouldn't be sortable):

```
<div class="multibuttonset">
<div class="button">
  <div class="active">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="button">
  <div class="active">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="button">
  <div class="inactive">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I'm aware that using the items option can control which items are sortable - I've got that code below:

```
$( "div.multibuttonset" ).sortable(
  { items: 'div.active' }
);
```

The trouble is that my sortable items are the divs with class .button, so when I use the above parameter it makes the children with class .active sortable, but not the parent (the div with class .button). Is there a way to place a ('div.active').parent()-type expression inside the { items } option of the .sortable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the [:has-selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)

```
$("div.multibuttonset").sortable({
    items: '.button:has(.active)'
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/FvmAE/)

Comment: Thanks @arun-p-johny - very straightforward!